# How to save the wallet state in monero-core?

Tags: development, monero-wallet-gui

I'm running Linux Mint 18 and I compiled the monero-core GUI from the development branch.  Every time I start the wallet, it has to refresh from the beginning of the blockchain.  I couldn't find a way to save the wallet state so that I don't have to go through that time consuming practice every time.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, however typing save or exit on the command line does nothing.  The command line just keeps refreshing.  The only way I can close the wallet is to either close the GUI by clicking the x in the upper right corner or by hitting Ctrl C in the command line, neither of which saves the wallets info.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the GUI part. Derp. Not sure, but I'd assume it should autosave occasionally and on exit. You should check the issues on GitHub and if one doesn't exist for this open one.

Answer (score 4):

Simply type:

```
save
```

on the command line, that will save the state of your balance at the current blockheight so it doesn't have to do it again next time it is loaded.

Comment: Also, if you close the wallet by typing 'exit' rather than just closing the window, then it should save the state as it shuts down.